# verificar se finalizou a compactação com zip php

Tags: php

Galera estou compactando uma pasta de foto do meu site para backup, uso o ZipArchive para fazer isso. Apos o zip ser criado eu fecho ele com o $zip->close();.

Como faço para o php dar um echo so depois que o arquivo zip for criado?

Comment: a seguir a `$zip->close();`, já tentou?

Comment: bom é o que estou tentando, mas estou com medo do echo ser executado com o arquivo sendo ripado. por ser um arquivo grande

Comment: Não se preocupe, isso (`o echo`) só vai executado depois do comendo `$zip->close();`

Comment: blz, acabei de fazer o teste aqui com um arquivo de 1gb hahahah muito obrigado galera.

Comment: :) de nada. Demora mas é assim mesmo